# Vim key map not registering

Tags: vim, dictionary, key, meta

I am trying to map Alt-r in Vim to save then execute the current file, and Alt-R to save then execute, but allow for extra parameters to be passed to the script.

In my vimrc I have the following (key mappings at the end of the file):

```
" Basic setup
set modeline
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

" Load pathoen
execute pathogen#infect()

" Solarized colourscheme
if has('gui_running')
    set background=light
else
    set background=dark
endif
colorscheme solarized

" Map Alt-r to run current file as if it were a script
nmap <M-r> :w<CR>:!./%<CR>
nmap <M-R> :w<CR>:!./%<Space>

" Allow Alt-<CursorKey> to move around windows
nmap <M-Up> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <M-Down> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <M-Left> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <M-Right> :wincmd l<CR>
```

The key mappings for window movement work fine, but Alt-r doesn't seem to do anything while Alt-R puts Vim into replace mode. I checked with :help M^r and :help M^R but they didn't list any mappings, nor does :map list those keys as taken. I have also already disabled Alt key mappings in the Gnome terminal.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

This could be a problem with [your terminal emulator which may encode the alt key different from what vim expects](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_Alt_key_to_work_in_terminal).

`Ctrl+v` causes vim (and most shells) to output the next character or key combination verbatim (literally). This way, you can [insert the keycode produced when you press `Alt+r` directly into your configuration file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip738) by adding

```
set <M-r>=^[r
set <M-R>=^[R
```

where the escaped characters like `^[x` have to be entered by pressing `Ctrl+v` and then `Alt+x` and may produce a different result on different terminal emulators.

Notice that there are no spaces around the equal signs. Vim would interpret additional spaces as part of the assignment which would make the directive misbehave.

Comment: `<C-v>` causes exactly no terminal emulators to output the next character or key combination literally. It is vim and shell feature to interpret `<C-v>` as “insert next key literally”. No, “insert ***one*** next key literally”. As almost all special sequences I know about contain exactly one special key which is the first you may think `<C-v>` applies to the whole sequence. But it does not. As an example of the case when it matters: there are some terminal emulators (at least aterm) that emit `<A-F1>` as `<Esc><F1>` (where `<F1>` was something starting with `<Esc>`).

Comment: Another difference is that `<C-v>u`, `<C-v>x`, `<C-v>U`, `<C-v>X`, `<C-v>{N}` (where `{N}` is some decimal digit), `<C-v>o` and `<C-v>O` are treated specially by vim, but not by shell.

Comment: And you have a mistake in `:set` lines: you must not use spaces around `=`. Guess it is yet another example of advice due to which you should never use [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com): I see exactly the same mistake in the linked article. AFAIR I have seen exactly no articles without stupid mistakes in them there.

Comment: The second article contains two lines that do the same thing in different ways. I guess nobody can explain me why `:set <M-a>=^[a` and `imap ^[a <M-a>` should be used together. By the way, I found another example of non-helpful `<C-v>`: konsole on my system for some reason generates `^X@s^[t` for `<M-t>`, `<C-v>` catches only `^X@s` part (`^X` is special and is the character affected by `<C-v>`, others are not affected, but until `^[` there are no special characters).

Comment: But its better to have bad formatted help than lack any directions. And now here we are on stackoverflow to improve upon the imprecision stated in vim.wikia.

Comment: Bad formatted is one thing. Incorrect is another. Most (not “all” now, but still …) articles I saw had mistake(s) that prevented advices from working. Some advices I saw were misleading. Not ever following best practices (like using `*nore*` commands without a very good reason for not using them) also seems like a rule there. As all articles have problems I come to a conclusion that no authors are proficient at Vim. Next conclusion in chain is that vim.wikia should be forgotten. You cannot really hope to change prevalent audience. Better to search SO or vim-use, or ask questions here or there.